# How can we pass Json object from servlet to JAVA class file?

Tags: java, json, servlets

How can we pass Json object from servlet to JAVA class file,? 
I'm new to Java developer and don't know how to call and access Json object in java class files from servlet..

Comment: Use a JSON mapper to unmarshal it into Java objects. There are plenty of those on the net like Jackson, Gson etc. and if you're running a JavaEE 7 compatible servlet container you might also be able to use the `javax.json` package. Grab one of those, read the documentation and try something.

Comment: How should I parse the json object values in java class file?

Comment: Well, I repeat: use a JSON mapper (malejpavouk provided an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import Jackson, which is a common library for JSON (de)serialization

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In your code use (writing this without ide, so there may be some tweaks needed)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject); //yourObject must have proper getters

servletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
servletResponse.getWriter().write(json);
servletResponse.getWriter().close(); //should flush on close automatically
```